Taping a drywall and Redgard’d cement board joint
I’m renovating a bathroom and I applied RedGard to my shower’s cement board. I decided to build out a wall and now have new drywall next to the RedGard’d cement board. Is too late to tape the joints now that the RedGard has been applied? Any and all recommendations welcome!

You can mud over the Redgard like it wasn't there, but I wouldn't. What I would do is tape and protect the Redgard from an excessive coverage of mud.
The tile is waterproof to a degree and you can run the mud under the tile a bit. I would say no more than an inch, to give it a number. Knowing where your tile will finish at, tape off on the shower side that 1" I was referring to. It can be less if you know exactly where the tile will finish. If you know the mud may get a little wild, you may need to run 2 or more passes of tape or maybe masking paper with it.
I would not concern myself with the build up either. The thinset used to bond the tile can be troweled up to the mud line after the tape is removed and the tile wil nest tightly to the mudded wall. I would paint the wall before tiling so when the grout or caulk is used to finish that edge of the tile, the paint will protect the mud from getting wiped off the wall while finishing the edge.

You can tape and mud the joints.
The compound will take a little longer to dry but all will be well.  Apply RedGuard to any area that will be subjected to water.
